# Each "Item_ID" is inserted 4 times into database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Each "Item_ID" with its data is inserted 4 times into database, here's my code:

```
            try {
                $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE Item_ID IN (" . implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']) . ")";
                $query = $pdo->query($sql);
                $orders = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if ($orders > 0) {
                    foreach ($orders as $order){
                    $item_id = $order['Item_ID'];
                    $price = $order['Price'];
                    $quantity = implode(', ', $_SESSION['qty_array']);
                    $quantity_array = explode(', ', $quantity);
                    foreach ($quantity_array as $qty) {
                    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO orders (user_id, item_id, name, email, phone, address, description, quantity, item_price, total_amount, payment_method) VALUES ( ? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
                    $stmt->execute([$user_id, $item_id, $name, $email, $phone, $address, $description, $qty, $price , $_SESSION['total'], $payment_method]);
                    }
                } 
            }

            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
```

I think the problem is with this line of code:

```
                    $quantity = implode(', ', $_SESSION['qty_array']);
                    $quantity_array = explode(', ', $quantity);
```

because quantity is changing for each one of the duplicated items but the item is the same.

Comment: Fundamentally, you seem to have two separate, unlinked pieces of data in the Session. You've got the cart - which presumably can have several items in it. You also have the quantity array - which presumably also have have several pieces of data in it. How do you know which quantity relates to which cart item? It doesn't appear to make sense to store them separately. More likely the cart should contain a set of associative arrays, which each entry listing the item ID and the quantity of that item in the cart. That way you can then only insert into `orders` once for each item.

Comment: `$quantity_array = explode(', ', $quantity);` makes no sense to declare.  Your already have `$_SESSION['qty_array']` to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for help everyone, Looking at my **cart.php** turned out I should set `$_SESSION['qty_array']` with index like this:

```
            try {
                $index = 0;
                $user_id = $_SESSION['uid'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE Item_ID IN (" . implode(',', $_SESSION['cart']) . ")";
                $query = $pdo->query($sql);
                while($order = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                        $item_id = $order['Item_ID'];
                        $price = $order['Price'];
                        $qty = $_SESSION['qty_array'][$index];
                        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO orders (user_id, item_id, name, email, phone, address, description, quantity, item_price, total_amount, payment_method) VALUES ( ? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
                        $stmt->execute([$user_id, $item_id, $name, $email, $phone, $address, $description, $qty, $price, $_SESSION['total'], $payment_method]);
                    $index ++;
                }
                
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
```